# J2ME Supprted Mobile Devices

Tags: java, java-me

Past day i just explored few android's techn for develop mobile application ,

After some day only i understand , That is android work on android OS mobiles ,

At last i understand android only work on android OS mobiles ,

So i discussed with some of seniors ,They advised ,

one tech  for all mobile's means go with J2ME ,

But i want some confirmation from our forums ,

Is it really possible or not ,

Also is it possible .

This j2me appication will work on all mobile Device ,

Are you sure j2me is platform independent ,

Advise ,

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not true.  None of Android, Windows Phone, or iPhone have built-in support for J2ME.

Comment: Then i should use diff tech for diff mobile ,That is for android i should develop with android tech, for blackberry i should go blackberry tech, for pda i go pda tech,

Comment: There are cross-platform technologies you can look into.  One option is to make your application HTML and JavaScript-based, using something like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).